# Ionic 3 - Firebase Push Notifications navigation back button not available

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, ionic3

I'm facing an issue on an Ionic 3 app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging. This happens on the Android debug build `android-debug.apk`. When the app is closed and removed from the `Overview` list, tapping on a notification redirects to the `EventComponent` but there is no back button. If the app is in the `Overview` list, the back button appears.

> payload

```
const payload = {
        "notification": {
          "title": "Your invitation has arrived",
          "body": eventSnapshot.name,
          "sound": "default",
          "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
          "icon": "fcm_push_icon"
        },
        "data": {
          "eventId": eventId,
          "uid": ids[key],
          "eventObj": JSON.stringify(eventSnapshot)
        }
      };
```

> app.component.ts

```
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  let isNotNotification = true;

  if (typeof FCMPlugin != 'undefined') {

    FCMPlugin.onNotification(function (data) {

      // let isNotification = true;

      if (data.wasTapped) {

        this.rootPage = TabsPage;
        isNotNotification = false;

        let key = data['eventId'];
        let notificationUid = data['uid'];
        let eventObj = data['eventObj'];

        try {
          appCtrl.getRootNav().push(EventComponent, {
            id: key,
            action: 'tapped',
            uid: notificationUid,
            eventObj: eventObj
          });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }

      } else {
        alert(JSON.stringify("not tapped" + JSON.stringify(data)));
      }
    },
      function (msg) {
        console.log('onNotification callback successfully registered: ' + msg);
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log('Error registering onNotification callback: ' + err);
      });
  }

  this.authService.afAuth.authState
    // .take(1)
    // .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe((auth) => this.doLoginStuff(auth, isNotNotification));
});
```

In `doLoginStuff` I only set the rootPage if `isNotNotification` is true.

```
if (isNotNotification) {
  this.rootPage = TabsPage;
}
```